# static_assert in function template with non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, static-assert

I have a function template with integer template parameter. I would like to provide an implementation for particular integers only. An attempt to use the function template with another argument should cause a compilation error.

I used `static_assert` in a way presented below.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct false_type : public std::false_type {};

template <int T>
void function() {
    static_assert(false_type<decltype(T)>::value, "Error");
};

template <>
void function<1>() {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    function<1>();
}
```

The code works nicely until `gcc 9.1` where it gives an `error: static assertion failed`.

I would like to know if there is a technique that would allow to ahieve my goal and that is compatible with `gcc 9.1`?

Comment: Try this: just declare the primary template, without implementation. As in `template <int T> void function();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That generates a [link time error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yn0Hk1Ro3LAL5oj9), rather than a compile time error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `static_assert` whose first argument is a non-dependent false constant is always "ill-formed, no diagnostic required", even in a template that is never instantiated. (So neither g++ nor clang++ is "incorrect" here.) In your function template, `T` is value-dependent but not type-dependent (its type is always `int`), so `decltype(T)` is not dependent, and neither is `false_type<int>::value`.

Could you have your `false_type` simply also take an `int` as parameter?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <int>
struct false_type : public std::false_type {};

template <int T>
void function() {
    static_assert(false_type<T>::value, "Error");
};

template <>
void function<1>() {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
     function<1>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I understood the phenomenon somewhere at the back of my mind but never in detail. The fact is that I use similar approach for type template parameters. And therefore `false_type` already exists for type template parameters.

Comment: Then maybe `false_type<std::integral_constant<int, T>>::value`.

Comment: Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 4):

GCC 9.1 seems to recognize that `false_type<decltype(T)>::value` doesn't really depend on `T`, which lets it evaluate the condition early (when first seeing the template, rather than on an instantination).

Here is a workaround:

```
template <auto V, auto...> inline constexpr auto dependent_value = V;

template <int T>
void function()
{
    static_assert(dependent_value<false, T>, "Error");
}
```

This way the compiler has to instantinate `function<T>` to evaluate `dependent_value<false, T>` (since `dependent_value` could have been specialized *after* the definition of `function<T>`).

---

Note that since no valid instantination can be generated for your implementation of `function<int T>`, the code in your question is [ill-formed, no diagnostic required](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1).

This workaround doesn't have this problem, since you could make a valid instantination of `function<int T>` by specializing `dependent_value` first.

---

There's also a simpler solution that doesn't involve `static_assert`:

```
template <int T> void function() = delete;
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand what the problem was with the original code when I first answered this, but now, thanks to the other respondents, I do, so it was worth it.

Anyway, one obvious solution would be to replace your three templates with:

```
template <int N>
void function() {
    static_assert(N == 1, "Error");
};
```

which [works fine in gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9OOZCr8lvazepie9).

clang and MSVC still compile the original code successfully, by the way.

Comment: Assuming `1` is the only specialization that OP needs.

Comment: @0x5453 Well, adapt `static_assert` to suit (obviously).